# xml parsing by shell

Tags: xml, shell, xml-parsing

I have an xml file , say example.xml:

```
                 <user>  
                  <host>

                  <jobid>23</jobid>                            

                  <instance>1</instance>
                  </host>
                 <host>
                    <jobid>25</jobid>
                    <instance>3</instance>
                  </host>
               </user>
```

I want to parse the second value of jobid that is 25 using shell script
but I am getting both the value of jobid that is 23 and 25
My shell script is  , say 
                    example.ksh

```
                 #!/usr/bin/ksh
                 JobId=$(grep -oPm2 "(?<=<jobid>)[^<]+" < example.xml)
                 echo $JobId
```

Please help me in getting the second value that is 25.
Thanks

Comment: could anyone help please....I have edited my question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the 2nd one:

```
JobId=$( grep -oP "(?<=<jobid>)[^<]+" example.xml | sed -n '2{p;q}' )
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use xml tool to process xml:

```
JobId=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//user/host[2]/jobid' -v . example.xml)
```